# two sequences and minimum steps to has same module

Tags: algorithm

I want a way to solve this problem.
we have two integer sequence `a[1...n]` and `b[1...n]`. each time we can choose a sub-sequence (Consecutive elements) from `a[1...n]` and add `x` (arbitrary number) to all of them. our goal is to in minimum number of steps, we have for each i: `a[i] = b[i] (module 5)`
(5 is an example of m in title of question)
restriction:

```
1 <= n <= 10^6
1 <= a[i],b[i] <= 10^9
```

for example:
a = 1 2
b = 3 4
minimum: 1
Is it possible to give a me a approach to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: please add the limitation of the problem. i.e. ? <= n <=? , ? <= a[i],b[i] <= ?

Comment: I add the restriction too.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem restatement

- We have two integer arrays `a` and `b`, of the same length `n`.
- We have a modulus `m`; `m = 5` in your example.
- Our goal is to change the values of `a` such that `(a[i] - b[i]) % m == 0` for all `i`.
- We want to reach the goal in the minimum number of steps.
- In each step, we add an arbitrary integer `x` to all of the consecutive elements `a[i]` through `a[j]`.
- Nothing has been said about how much computation we can do for each step. We will try to minimize it, but if we have to spend quadratic, cubic, even factorial time, that would seem to be allowed.

## Analysis

First, observe that we can simplify the problem quite a bit by setting all of the `b` values to zero and adjusting each value of `a[i]` to `(a[i] - b[i]) % m`. Then we just ignore `b`, we only consider values of `a` modulo `m`, and the goal becomes “all values in `a` must be zero”. For example:

```
m = 5
a = [1234, 5678, 9012, 3456]
b = [3141, 2718, 1414, 4242]
```

Simplifies to:

```
a = [3, 0, 3, 4]
```

Clearly, we can reach the goal by simply changing each nonzero value individually. Can we improve on that? Sometimes. For example, this can be solved in two steps:

```
a = [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3]
```

A slightly more complex example takes four steps:

```
a = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3]
   + 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
a = [0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3]
   do the rest individually
```

As far as I can see, whenever we have a run of numbers that begins and ends with the same number, there is no penalty for changing them all to zero out the endpoints:

```
a = [..., 3, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 3, ...]
   +      2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
a = [..., 0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0, ...]
```

This zeroes out two numbers in one step. The intervening numbers are no worse off, unless they were all zero, and even then, the total steps are two either way.

## Algorithm

Here’s an algorithm that seems pretty optimal, though I can’t prove it rigorously:

```
range = entire array
while true:
    move endpoints inward to skip zeroes
    if endpoints pass each other:
        everything is zero, halt
    if endpoints have equal value X:
        add (5 - X) % m to range, which will zero out endpoints
        loop
    (endpoints are unequal)
    for each endpoint:
        identify the "run" of equal numbers R at the endpoint
          (might be just one)
        skip any zeroes after the run ("after" means "inward")
        identify the next number N after the run and zeroes
    if N of endpoint x equals R of endpoint y:
        zero out the run at endpoint x
        this will set up an advantageous equal-endpoint in next step
        loop
    (neither N equaled opposite R)
    zero out whichever run is longer
    loop
```

## Example

Let’s apply this to the example data above and see how it works.

```
a = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3]

range = 2 1 2 2 1 2 0 3
no zeroes to skip at ends
unequal endpoints
left run: R = 2, N = 1
right run: R = 3, N = 2
N of right run = R of left run
zero out right run
range = 2 1 2 2 1 2 0 0
steps = 1
loop

range = 2 1 2 2 1 2 0 0
skip zeroes
range = 2 1 2 2 1 2
equal endpoints
add 3 to range
range = 0 4 0 0 4 0
steps = 2
loop

range = 0 4 0 0 4 0
skip zeroes
range = 4 0 0 4
equal endpoints
add 1 to range
range = 0 1 1 0
steps = 3
loop

range = 0 1 1 0
skip zeroes
range = 1 1
equal endpoints
add 4 to range
range = 0 0
steps = 4
loop

range = 0 0
skip zeroes
endpoints passed each other
halt
```

The algorithm took 4 steps as expected.